# Flatten BigQuery Table with JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY - No matching signature for function JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

How can I best flatten a table with a JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY query that flattens the below table?

[image]

I tried:

```
with raw as (
    select *
    from {{ source('hubspot','deal_pipelines') }} 
),
temp as (
select JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(stages,'$') as stages
from raw
)
select
    json_value(s,'$.label') as label
    ,json_value(s,'$.active') as active
from temp ,unnest(stages) as s
```

But I get this error:

```
No matching signature for function JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY for argument types: ARRAY<STRUCT<value STRUCT<probability FLOAT64, displayorder INT64, active BOOL, ...>>>, STRING. Supported signatures: JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(STRING, [STRING]); JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(JSON, [STRING]) at [18:8]
```

Any suggestions how to fix it are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stages` has a type of `ARRAY<STRUCT<value STRUCT<probability FLOAT64, displayorder INT64, active BOOL, ...>>>`, not a *JSON* string. So you seem to want below.

```sql
with raw as (
    select *
    from {{ source('hubspot','deal_pipelines') }} 
)
select
    s.value.label as label,
    s.value.active as active
from raw, unnest(stages) as s;
```